Android webView url not loading properly https://wolt.com/sk/login
I'm trying to load https://wolt.com/sk/login" page and do automatic login in my application.
I also tried Android-AdvancedWebView  https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/master/Source/sample/src/main/java/im/delight/android/examples/webview/MainActivity.java but same result
Thank you for help.
this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
    } else {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    }

    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // enable DOM storage
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); // allow access to file system
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true); // allow access to file system from file URLs
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true); // allow access to file system from any URLs
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);

    WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            Log.i("webview", "loading: deprecation");
            return  true;
            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            Log.i("webview", "loading: build.VERSION_CODES.N");
            return true;
            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(
                WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
           Log.i("webview", "page started:"+url);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

            Log.i("webview", "page finished:"+url);

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

    });
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    webView.loadUrl("https://wolt.com/sk/login");
    // use cookies to remember a logged in status
     cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);


Please Add below code in your file
    mWebview  = new WebView(this);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
            // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
            onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
        }
    });

    mWebview .loadUrl("https://wolt.com/sk/login/22");
    setContentView(mWebview );

}


Hi I tried, but it wont' work:
https://pastebin.com/svB0GjB8
There is my code.
With https://wolt.com/sk/login/ show page but buttons for login are unavailable. And with https://wolt.com/sk/login/22 it show empy page.
